# Product images and descriptions on web store – copyright issues (Ireland/EU law)

Tags: legal, copyright

I’m looking to sell some products online into a foreign market (which likes this Irish product). So I need to put images and production descriptions on my site.

I’m not buying directly from the manufacturer as they will not deal with a small company like me, but have sourced the product from a distributor, and have been frank and open with them about my plans.

If I take a picture of the product myself, can I publish that picture?

The product packaging has information and specs on the product written on it – could I reproduce this, or parts of, in a foreign language?

There is a [similar question here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47703/can-i-use-product-images-from-official-websites) which is asked by an Indian person and answered by a Canadian,  does anyone here know this from an Irish or EU law perspective?

Comment: In general, posting a picture of a product doesn't constitute a copyright violation since you're not asserting the work is your own. eBay and Amazon would be replete with infringements otherwise. The same thing goes for descriptive information and specs. What you'd need permission for however is using logos, trademarks, and copyrighted material that wasn't altered _substantially_, which translation may qualify as. Most manufacturers publish their acceptable use policy somewhere on their sites, so I'd look for that, or contact them directly for clarification/permission.

Comment: @dan - just seeing this now, thanks. Do you know if Irish law is the same? Also, suppose that "Acme" is  leading food brand - would I have an issue with "Acme baked beans" as a product listing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the specifics of Irish law, however, you could just view listings for products for that country in eCommerce shops, eBay, and Amazon...I doubt it would be any different. You should be fine to list a product under its name, providing you don't copy any trademarked logos or content from their holders (i.e., the manufacturer or licensee) without their permission. I'd suggest checking their websites for a terms of use or trademark page, and asking for permission is never a bad idea either.